# Ordered Dictionary and Sorting

Tags: python, sorting, for-loop, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to solve a simple practice test question:

> Parse the CSV file to:
>
> - Find only the rows where the user started before September 6th, 2010.
> - Next, order the values from the "words" column in ascending order (by start date)
> - Return the compiled "hidden" phrase

The csv file has 19 columns and 1000 rows of data. Most of which are irrelevant. As the problem states, we're only concerned with sorting the the start_date column in ascending order to get the associated word from the 'words' column. Together, the words will give the "hidden" phrase.

The dates in the source file are in UTC time format so I had to convert them. I'm at the point now where I think I've got the right rows selected, but I'm having issues sorting the dates.

Here's my code:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
from datetime import datetime


with open('TSE_sample_data.csv', 'rb') as csvIn:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvIn)
    for row in reader:

        #convert from UTC to more standard date format
        startdt = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(row['start_date']))
        new_startdt = datetime.strftime(startdt, '%Y%m%d')        

        # find dates before Sep 6th, 2010
        if new_startdt < '20100906':

            # add the values from the 'words' column to a list 
            words = []
            words.append(row['words'])

            # add the dates to a list
            dates = []
            dates.append(new_startdt)

            # create an ordered dictionary to sort the dates... this is where I'm having issues 
            dict1 = OrderedDict(zip(words, dates))
            print dict1
            #print list(dict1.items())[0][1]
            #dict2 = sorted([(y,x) for x,y in dict1.items()])
            #print dict2
```

When I `print dict1` I'm expecting to have one ordered dictionary with the words and the dates included as items. Instead, what I'm getting is multiple ordered dictionaries for each key-value pair created.

Comment: Next time rubber duck debugging fixes it, simply don't post. It's unlikely that anyone else will find this useful.

Comment: Yes, of course you would! It would have been super helpful *specifically to you*. My point is that it's *only* useful specifically to you. How would another person with the same problem find this, or use your answer to solve their problem, unless they were writing *almost exactly the same code*? SO is about creating high quality questions and answers, see the [tour]. I appreciate that you're making an effort, and I've glad you've solved your problem, but that doesn't make this useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the corrected version:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
from datetime import datetime


with open('TSE_sample_data.csv', 'rb') as csvIn:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvIn)
    words = []
    dates = []
    for row in reader:

        #convert from UTC to more standard date format
        startdt = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(row['start_date']))
        new_startdt = datetime.strftime(startdt, '%Y%m%d')        

        # find dates before Sep 6th, 2010
        if new_startdt < '20100906':

            # add the values from the 'words' column to a list 
            words.append(row['words'])
            # add the dates to a list
            dates.append(new_startdt)

    # This is where I was going wrong! Had to move the lines below outside of the for loop
    # Originally, because I was still inside the for loop, I was creating a new Ordered Dict for each "row in reader" that met my if condition
    # By doing this outside of the for loop, I'm able to create the ordered dict storing all of the values that have been found in tuples inside the ordered dict
    # create an ordered dictionary to sort by the dates
    dict1 = OrderedDict(zip(words, dates))
    dict2 = sorted([(y,x) for x,y in dict1.items()])

    # print the hidden message
    for i in dict2: 
        print i[1]
```

Comment: And this answer is completely useless. It has no explanation of what the problem was, what you've changed or how those changes solve it. Again, when you realise you've made a trivial error, you can assume that won't be a useful Q&A for SO.